# Using a created ruleset to classify data dependent upon values in 2 different columns within a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

[image]

I have a data frame which contains the relative basal area (relBA) for unique species collected in plots. I am trying to create a new column that indicates if a plot would be class 1, 2, or 3, based off the following ruleset:

Class 1 = the relBA of the most abundant species (i.e., highest relBA value within a given plot) is >0.5 and > 2*relBA of the 2nd most abundant species.

Class 2 = the relBA of the 1st plus the 2nd most abundant >= 0.8 and the relBA of the 2nd most abundant species is >0.2 + relBA of the 3rd most abundant species

Class 3 = all other conditions.

However, I am relatively new to using R and am not sure how to do this (or how to google it in a manner to find examples). Can someone point me to an example or provide code that could help? Thank you.

I have not tried any current code as I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of data - rather provide the output of `dput()` of your data.

Comment: To add details to Phil's comment - we can't test answers on a picture of data. `dput()` is a command that makes copy/pastable versions code to reproduce data. If you run `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` and share the result we'll be able to replicate the first 10 rows of your data, which will allow us to test answers.

Comment: It would also help a lot if you would share the expected output for the first 10 rows (or whatever sample you share with `dput()`). That we we can tell if we're getting the right answer or not.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the advice. I am away from my computer now, but will provide the dput() results when I get back tomorrow. Is there a specific way I need to provide the output or do I just copy and paste it into the post?